# How to toggle touch event between nested Relative layouts?

Tags: android

I have a Relative layout holds a surface view and another Relative layout (Nested)..

1 )  I want to receive touch events separately for Surface view, if touch events are out of child relative layout. ??

2) if my touch events falls on child relative layout, then the current touch event should not go to surface view.

How to achieve this toggle ???

Thanks in advance..!

Below is my Activity:

```
public class DragAndDropBasicActivity extends Activity implements  OnTouchListener {
    private RelativeLayout letterView;                      
    private RelativeLayout mainLayout;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        letterView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mlKnobView);
        letterView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    private boolean dragging = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean eventConsumed = true;
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (v == letterView) {
                dragging = true;
                eventConsumed = false;
            }
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            dragging = false;
            eventConsumed = false;

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (v != letterView) {
                if (dragging) {
                    setAbsoluteLocationCentered(letterView, x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        return eventConsumed;

    }

    private void setAbsoluteLocationCentered(View v, int x, int y) {
        setAbsoluteLocation(v, x - v.getWidth() / 2, y - v.getHeight() / 2);
    }


    private void setAbsoluteLocation(View v, int x, int y) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        alp.leftMargin = x;
        alp.topMargin = y;
        v.setLayoutParams(alp);
    }
}
```

Below my Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mlKnobView"
        android:layout_width="260dip"
        android:layout_height="260dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
        android:background="@drawable/border" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_down"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="140dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_down"
            android:text="Down" />

        <com.example.RotaryKnob
            android:id="@+id/jogView"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_down"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_up"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_left"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_down"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/jogView"
            android:background="@drawable/button_left"
            android:text="Left" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_right"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_down"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button_left"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button_left"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/jogView"
            android:background="@drawable/button_right"
            android:text="Right" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_up"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="140dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_left"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_down"
            android:layout_below="@+id/windowHeader"
            android:background="@drawable/button_up"
            android:text=" UP " />

    </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="Hai" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have added my code..